# How would this login authentication code look in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies

I need help with this code snippet, it is in ASP.NET MVC, I would like to pass it to ASP.NET CORE MVC, however some things I am not finding the similar in ASP.NET core.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    VMLogin vm = new VMLogin();
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(VMLogin vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Usuario usuarioDb = db.Usuarios.Where(u => u.Login == vm.Login).FirstOrDefault();

        if (usuarioDb == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Não existe usuário com este Login");
            return View(vm);
        }

        bool senhaConfere = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(usuarioDb.Senha, vm.Senha);

        if (!senhaConfere)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Senha incorreta");
            return View(vm);
        }

        string authId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Session["AuthID"] = authId;

        var cookie = new HttpCookie("AuthID");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        cookie.Value = authId;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        usuarioDb.AuthId = authId;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(vm);
}

public ActionResult Logout()
{
    if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("AuthID"))
    {
        String authId = Request.Cookies["AuthID"].Value;
        Usuario usuarioDb = db.Usuarios.Where(c => c.AuthId == authId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (usuarioDb != null)
        {
            usuarioDb.AuthId = "";
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        Request.Cookies.Remove("AuthID");

        if (Session["AuthID"] != null)
        {
            Session.Remove("AuthID");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: So you want us to convert your ASP.Net MVC code to ASP.Net Core MVC? If so, did you try it yourself and what problems are you exactly stumbling upon while trying so.

Comment: They will remain same if you stick in your own identity framework. Both MVC 5 and Core are producing same frontend page.

Comment: Session["AuthID"], Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains, Request.Cookies.Remove...  These examples do not find references in ASP.NET CORE

Comment: You need to firstly learn the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1